# MathJax rendering changes scrolling position

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax

When I follow a link to an answer (e.g. [my answer here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/1930/1120)), the page is scrolled to the correct position. But then MathJax renders all the formulas, thus shifting content around, at which point the scroll position is no longer correct.

Can you add some JavaScript to run after MathJax has formatted the LaTeX on the page, to correct the scroll position again?

Comment: This kind of things that may depend on your browser. What browser are you using, what version, under what operating system?

Comment: Results reproducible in: Firefox 13, Waterfox 12, Opera 11.64 and Chrome 19.0.1084.46 on Windows 8 Consumer Preview x64.

Comment: I can confirm that for FF10 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MathJax v2.0 added the ability to position to the location in the hash reference of the URL after MathJax finished processing the math, but it has some unwanted consequences for some pages, and so was off by default.  MathJax v2.1 (in beta at the moment, scheduled for release within the next two weeks) should resolve those problems and so has this feature on by default. So if you are using the MathJax CDN with the `mathjax/latest` URL, you should start seeing your desired behavior shortly.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be fixed now, even though you have to wait until [all maths on the site have been compiled](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/538/viewing-single-answers-in-math-heavy-threads-takes-too-long) before the position is reset.