# Viewing single answers in math-heavy threads takes too long

Tags: support, feature-request, mathjax, user-interface

MathJax is applied from top to bottom. That is often okay, but in cases like [this one](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/2823/98) it disrups the experience; you have to wait quite a while (depending on your CPU) until a lower-ranked answer (you were directly linked to) is properly typeset. (That, and it [moves away](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358/mathjax-rendering-changes-scrolling-position).)

MathJax allows to [control the order of execution](http://www.mathjax.org/docs/1.1/typeset.html); it would be useful to give precedence to the post in a thread that the URL points to (and, for comments, give precedence to other comments on the same post and the post itself before other content).